# How to automate CefBrowserWindow in another process

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, ui-automation, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to pragmatically click a link inside `CefBrowserWindow` in another process.
I know I could use `SendInput`, but I want to know if there are anther more reliable ways?

Or, is there a way to get the html content in `CefBrowserWindow` of another process? I don't want the source html, but the final content after rendering.

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:ui-automation]. The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ui-automation/info) offers *"Examples of UI Test Frameworks/Libraries"*.

Comment: At first, you can use [accessibility tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) to check what's kind of control you want to click. And then check if you can click it using Invoke.Invoke of the [Action menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects#interact-with-ui-elements). If you can click it through accessibility tool then you can automate it using [UI Automation technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT It's an `<a>` link of html inside CefBrowserWindow. It seems that UI automation tool could list the content, I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @user1633272 Has this issue been solved?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT UIA can access it, however when the window is minimized, UIA can not read the elements inside CefBrowserWindow. Do you know if there are another technologies?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT can MSAA access invisible window?

Comment: @user1633272 Simply test notepad window just now, when it is minimized, I can still scroll down via Inspect tool (UI Automation mode). However I don't have a CefBrowserWindow control for testing.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT is that because you initialize the UIA before notepad minimized?

Comment: @user1633272 No. I open the notepad and minimize it at first, then open then Inspect tool.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT In my case, the child items disappear after the parent is minimized. You are right, the root window is still in the tree of inspect tool, but all 'invisible' child windows (without WS_VISIBLE) are gone.

Comment: @user1633272 Could you share an example application of `CefBrowserWindow` so I can do a further investigation?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT that's a commercial software requires login. You can try any list view with a vertical scroll-bar. UIA is such a pain, it can not do anything with 'invisible' elements which are in a list out of the client area.

Comment: @user1633272 Yes, I can reproduce this issue. When the window is minimized, the list view items are not able to found by UI Automation. Maybe [cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationcacherequest-addpattern) helps.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I don't think it helps, because those elements are not even in `Raw View` in Inspect.exe. It seems that UIA is designed for human behaviour replacement, that's why it can not deal with invisible elements.